# Restore Windows 10 Calculator when minimized or running in background

Tags: c#, restore

I am using C# trying to restore the Windows 10 Calculator when minimized or running in the background. I am trying the following code but it's not working.

```
     if (calcrunning == true & calcresponding == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Running but suspended or minimized ");
            //RunCalculator();
            IntPtr calcwindow = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Calculator");
            //ResumeProcess(calcwindow.Handle);
            //ShowWindow(calcwindow, SW_MINIMIZE);
            //ResumeThread(calcwindow);
            //calc.Start();
            ShowWindow(calcwindow, SW_SHOW);
            ShowWindow(calcwindow, SW_RESTORE);
            SetForegroundWindow(calcwindow);
       }        
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern int ResumeThread(IntPtr hThread);
```

Any ideas? SetForegroundWindow only works if the calculator is not minimized. Is it failing because it's a modern app?

Answer (score 1):

Application lifecycle for UWP is very clear about the suspended state. On Desktop family, UWP apps suspend when they are minimized or when Windows enters a low power state.

A [uservoice has been raised on wpdev.uservoice.com](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/9950598-exclude-suspending-in-desktop) where Microsoft is listening suggestions. You are highly encouraged to vote on it.

Answer (score 0):

[`SetForegroundWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation pretty clearly states restrictions on use. Generally, you can't bring arbitrary windows to front.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

                SetForegroundWindow(calcwindow);
                ShowWindowAsync(calcwindow, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

It put it on the foreground even if it's minimized